# Import or parse list in R

Tags: r

I have a CSV file in which one of the fields contains some coordinates stored liked that:

```
"TRIP_ID","COORDINATES"

"T1","[[-8.585676,41.148522],[-8.585712,41.148639],[-8.585685,41.148855],[-8.58573,41.148927],[-8.585982,41.148963]]"

"T2","[[-8.610876,41.14557],[-8.610858,41.145579],[-8.610903,41.145768]]"

...
```

When I import this in R what I obtain is a data frame with two columns. The problem is the class of the column "COORDINATES". Both *charachters* or *fragments* are of little use in my case.

What I want to achieve is to have these datas stored in a list or in a vector, so that i can write something like **df$COORDINATES[1][1]** AND GET **-8.585676,41.148522**.

How can I do that?
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like JSON notation for nested lists. So you can use one of the JSON packages:

```
tmp.txt='"TRIP_ID","COORDINATES"
"T1","[[-8.585676,41.148522],[-8.585712,41.148639],[-8.585685,41.148855],[-8.58573,41.148927],[-8.585982,41.148963]]"
"T2","[[-8.610876,41.14557],[-8.610858,41.145579],[-8.610903,41.145768]]"
'

 df = read.csv(text=tmp.txt,stringsAsF=FALSE)
```

Now we can decode an element and get a matrix:

```
> require(jsonlite)
> fromJSON(df$COORDINATES[2])
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -8.610876 41.14557
[2,] -8.610858 41.14558
[3,] -8.610903 41.14577
```

That's probably most of the work done, it all depends on what you want to do next. You could create a list of matrices:

```
Clist = lapply(df$COORDINATES, fromJSON)
```

then to get the data for a given row of your data frame you index into the list:

```
> Clist[[1]]
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -8.585676 41.14852
[2,] -8.585712 41.14864
[3,] -8.585685 41.14885
[4,] -8.585730 41.14893
[5,] -8.585982 41.14896
> Clist[[2]]
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -8.610876 41.14557
[2,] -8.610858 41.14558
[3,] -8.610903 41.14577
```

If this is what it looks like, namely lat-long coordinates of GPS tracks or similar, you might want to convert them to SpatialLinesDataFrames - check out the `sp` package and the Spatial Task View.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option using the `strapply` function in the gsubfn package:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> tmp.txt <- '"TRIP_ID","COORDINATES"
+ "T1","[[-8.585676,41.148522],[-8.585712,41.148639],[-8.585685,41.148855],[-8.58573,41.148927],[-8.585982,41.148963]]"
+ "T2","[[-8.610876,41.14557],[-8.610858,41.145579],[-8.610903,41.145768]]"
+ '
> 
> df <- read.table(text=tmp.txt, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header=TRUE)
> 
> coords <- strapply(df$X..COORDINATES, 
+                    '\\[(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*),(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\]',
+                    FUN=function(one,two) c(as.numeric(one),as.numeric(two)),
+                    combine=list)
> str(coords)
List of 2
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ : num [1:2] -8.59 41.15
  ..$ : num [1:2] -8.59 41.15
  ..$ : num [1:2] -8.59 41.15
  ..$ : num [1:2] -8.59 41.15
  ..$ : num [1:2] -8.59 41.15
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : num [1:2] -8.61 41.15
  ..$ : num [1:2] -8.61 41.15
  ..$ : num [1:2] -8.61 41.15
> coords[[1]][[1]]
[1] -8.585676 41.148522
```

This assumes that there will always be at least 1 digit before the decimal point (no -.123), it can be extended to include that case as well if needed.  This creates a separate list, but that list can be assigned as a column in the original data frame if you really want.

Comment: Another option using `base R` is. `lapply(strsplit(df[,2], '[][]'), function(x) lapply(strsplit(grep('[0-9]', x, value=TRUE), ','), as.numeric))`